# Creating "heatmap" based on data with legend in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, legend, heat-map

I am new to QGIS.

I need to make a map that looks like a heatmap, but is based on data values, not point concentrations, and with a legend. I was able to make a heatmap based on data values, but not able to create a legend also based on the data values instead of the point concentrations.

I also tried making a raster map, but the map values seem to be based on point concentration instead of the data values.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try the heat map plugin... you should be able to tweak it to get meaningful results and thus a legend.

Comment: That's what I've been using. My data is in the range of -1E-13 to 1E13 but the legend gives me values of 0-6 (points in that area).

Comment: This rather looks like a problem of surface interpolation instead of making a heat map. You might try some methods like **v.surf.rst** or **v.surf.idw** from processing toolbox. This results in raster, thus you also have much better control on legend creation.